# System.UnauthorizedAccessException при записи в реестр

Tags: c#, реестр

Тривиальная задача. Добавить в ветку

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

ключ. Как я это делаю:

```
static void SetRegistryValue(string path, string key, object value)
{
    using (var currKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(path, true))
    {
        if (currKey != null)
        {
            currKey.SetValue(key, value, RegistryValueKind.ExpandString);
            currKey.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Потом

```
SetRegistryValue(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", "key", "value");
```

В итоге вываливается в

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Попытка выполнить несанкционированную операцию.

После этого что я только не перепробовал. Протестировал даже с *level="highestAvailable"* в манифесте - тоже самое.

У меня на борту Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview. Провел тест на машине с Windows 7 - все прекрасно работает. В чем проблема?

Comment: Похожий вопрос на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768172/c-sharp-registry-setvalue-throws-unauthorizedaccessexception Автор утверждает, что проблема была в антивирусе, в ответах есть и другие предложения.

Comment: Спасибо. Не думал, что бесплатный 360 Internet Security так категорично не пускает в автозапуск.

Comment: @EduardGushchin: А вы его на секундочку отключите и посмотрите, что получится.

Comment: @VladD: Да, в логах уже посмотрел. Просто даже мысли про него не было.

Comment: Если проблема решена, то [опубликуйте решение в ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) и отметьте его как правильный.

Comment: @defaultlocale: Поскольку идея ваша, то имеет смысл, чтобы вы опубликовали решение (и получили заслуженные баллы).

Comment: @VladD спасибо, но чтобы ответ был полезен нужно включить конкретную информацию (что именно блокировалось, как отключить блокировку, как проверить), которой я не обладаю. Писать же развернутый ответ (a-la что нужно проверять в таких случаях) мне лень :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доступ к ключам автозапуска в реестре без предупреждения блокировал антивирус 360 Internet Security.